# Save 16-bit numpy arrays as 16-bit PNG image

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, png

I'm trying to save a 16-bit numpy array as a 16-bit PNG but what I obtain is only a black picture. I put here a minimum example of what I'm talking aboout.

```
im = np.random.randint(low=1, high=6536, size=65536).reshape(256,256) #sample numpy array to save as image
plt.imshow(im, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

[image]

Given the above numpy array this is the image I see with matplotlib, but when then I save the image as 16-bit png I obtain the picture below:

```
import imageio

imageio.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

Image saved:

[image]

where some light grey spots are visible but the image is substantially black. Anyway when I read back the image and visualize it again with matplotlib I see the same starting image. I also tried other libraries instead of `imageio` (like `PIL` or `PyPNG`) but with the same result.

I know that 16-bit image values range from 0 to 65535 and in the array numpy array here there only values from 1 to 6536, but I need to save numpy arrays images similar to this, i.e. where the maximum value represented in the image isn't the maximum representable value. I think that some sort of nornalization is involved in the saving process. I need to save the array exactly as I see them in matplotlib at their maximum resolution and without compression or shrinkage in their values (so division by 255 or conversion to 8-bit array are not suitable).

Comment: look for uncompressed formats like `.tif` .
formats like `.jpg` or `.png` will always apply some kind of compression.

Comment: @JacoSolari, PNG is a lossless format, so the compression is not a problem.

Comment: @Aelius, note that matplotlib's `imshow` will, in effect, normalize the range of colors shown in the plot.  To see the "true" color scale for unsigned 16 bit integers, use `plt.imshow(im, cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=0, vmax=65535)`.

Comment: You are right Warren! Do you know if there's some method with whoch I can achieve this normalization on the maximum value also when saving the image as PNG? I need to save the array as I see it in matpotlib

Comment: The values in your example range from 1 to 6535.  If you want the 16 bit grayscale image to have a full range from black to white, you'll have to scale the values to the range [0, 65535].  But the impression given in the question is that you don't want to scale the values.  If scaling the data before saving it is OK, check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like `imageio.imwrite` will do the right thing if you convert the data type of the array to `numpy.uint16` before writing the PNG file:

```
imageio.imwrite('result.png', im.astype(np.uint16))
```

When I do that, `result.png` is a 16 bit gray-scale PNG file.

If you want the image to have the full grayscale range from black to white, you'll have to scale the values to the range [0, 65535].  E.g. something like:

```
im2 = (65535*(im - im.min())/im.ptp()).astype(np.uint16)
```

Then you can save that array with

```
imageio.imwrite('result2.png', im2)
```

---

For writing a NumPy array to a PNG file, an alternative is [`numpngw`](https://pypi.org/project/numpngw/) (a package that I created).  For example,

```
from numpngw import write_png

im2 = (65535*(im - im.min())/im.ptp()).astype(np.uint16)
write_png('result2.png', im2)
```

If you are already using `imageio`, there is probably no signficant advantage to using `numpngw`.  It is, however, a much lighter dependency than `imageio`--it depends only on NumPy (no dependence on PIL/Pillow and no dependence on `libpng`).

Comment: When I try this with `imageio.imwrite` I get the message "Lossy conversion from uint16 to uint8. Losing 8 bits of resolution. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning."

Comment: It still works for me, with numpy 1.26.1 and imageio 2.31.6 in Python 3.12.0.  Are you saving the image as a **PNG** file?  If you double-check that the code that you are running is the same as shown here and you still get that error, you should create a new question about it.

Comment: Looking at the `imageio` docs, it looks like it might delegate to a range of different libraries, and perhaps the functionality depends on what is installed. In any case, `numpngw` solved it for me, so thank you for creating that!